# rails redirect_to notice - how to apply css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

I issue the following command in my users_controller.rb:

```
format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
```

The notice shows up properly at the top of my root page, but I can't seem to apply any css styling to it.

In application.css I have put the following:

```
#flash_notice {
  padding: 5px 8px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #CFC;
  border: solid 1px #6C6;
}
```

But it has no effect. I have also tried .notice and #notice but they have no effect either. So how can I apply styling to the notice?

Thanks for your help.

RailsNewman

Comment: What does the generated markup look like for the message?

Comment: Good point.  I am an idiot for not looking at that.  Here is the top part of the source after it displays the Successfully logged in! message:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

Successfully logged in!


<head>
  <title>Famcare</title>


So that tells me there is NO class associated with the notice generated.  Is that correct and if so, how should I go about styling this.  BTW I am trying to simply copy the formatting used by Ryan from Railscasts, episode 160, where he has the notices shown in green with a dark green border.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at your `application.html.erb`. You should have something like:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="flash <%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

If so, the `class` will be `.success` or `.error`:

```
.success {
}
.error {
}
```

Comment: the top portion of my application.html.erb is shown below.  I am a complete newbie but I read this to be that the message is going into the <%= notice %>.  So wouldn't that class be "notice"? If not, could you explain, for my education, how I would determine the class?  Thanks.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<%= notice %>
<%= alert %>

<head>
  <title>Famcare</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

Comment: thanks gabrielhilal, you gave me the clue I needed.  I used the following code to replace the <%= notice %> :

    <%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
        <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
    <%- end -%>